# How can you get a multiple output in json in just one loop?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, foreach

I did fetch from the URL and I got the data from forEach my problem is there is 2 div inside innerHTML
with col-6 so it will be 2 column in 1 row so it will look like this -> [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkCeq.png) but i wanted to get the next line of the array on the second div is that possible so it will have 2 different data

```
 fetch(URL)
.then(data=>data.json())
.then(data=>{
 data.forEach(datas => {
document.querySelector('.more-from').innerHTML += `
<div class="row related">

 <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <a href="${datas.post_name}"><div class="post position-relative mb-4" style="background-image:url('${datas.image}'); height:175px;">
  </div></a>
  <a href="${datas.post_name}" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to ${datas.post_title}" class="post-title"><span style="font-weight:bold; font-family:oswald, 
  sans-serif !important;font-size: 17px; line-height: 22px; color: #333;">${datas.post_title} 
  </span></a>
 </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <a href="${datas.post_name}"><div class="post position-relative mb-4" style="background-image:url('${datas.image}'); height:175px;">
  </div></a>
  <a href="${datas.post_name}" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to ${datas.post_title}" class="post-title"><span style="font-weight:bold; font-family:oswald, 
  sans-serif !important;font-size: 17px; line-height: 22px; color: #333;">${datas.post_title} 
  </span></a>
 </div>

</div>`;
```

**ITS ONLY GETTING THE FIRST ID WHICH IS 10893 FOR BOTH DIV.**
[image: Console log of data]

Comment: `col-md-6 col-lg-6` perhaps change the 6's to 12's - though, I may have misunderstood the image

Comment: there's no problem with the arrangement of column but as you can see in the image,title all data is same on left and right i wanted the second div to have the second value of json i updated the console log so you can see the first one id is the only one that i'm getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a regular `for` with index:

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i = i + 2) {
    const div1Data = data[i];
    const div2Data = data[i+1]
    document.querySelector('.more-from').innerHTML += `...`
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much if i wanted to add another do i just need to create     const div3Data = data[i+2]?

Comment: If you'd want another one you'll need to make the "i + 3" add another const, and copy your code block. In my answer you'd just need to change the "% 2" to "% 3" and you would need to add your code for your column only once.

Comment: @MarkMendoza yes, but also `let i = 0; i < data.length - 2; i = i + 3` in the `for` setup.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a normal for loop as @Onheiron suggests, only I would use a modulo check to get less repetitive code.

e.g.

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i = i++) {

    if(i % 2 === 0)
        document.querySelector('.more-from').innerHTML += `<row>`;
   
    document.querySelector('.more-from').innerHTML += `<your element only once>`

    if(i % 2 === 0)
        document.querySelector('.more-from').innerHTML += `</row>`;
}
```

if you'd set the value to check the modulo against to a variable you could also easily change it to get 3 columns.